# how to use unix_timestamp in query builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

While I want to get UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in the query this is what happens:

Code:

```
$this->db->where(array('is_active' => 1, 'time' => 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'));
$this->db->update('table', array('is_active' => 0));
```

Result:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `is_active` = 0 WHERE `is_active` = 1 AND `time` = 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'
```

I want `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` without quotes and not like `'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `time` function of PHP which is equivalent to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

```
$this->db->where('is_active',1);
$this->db->where('time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()',null, FALSE);
$this->db->update('table', array('is_active' => 0));
```

You can use third parameter of where clause as `false`

If `time` is `timestamp` you can simply use `time()` function of PHP as

```
$this->db->where(array('is_active' => 1, 'time' => time()));
$this->db->update('table', array('is_active' => 0));
```

Comment: I know bro but I wanna know how to use unix timestamp in ci as there are other functions in mysql that may not have equivalence in php

Comment: If `time` is `timestamp` then you can simply use this else check my updated answer

Comment: Are you getting any errro

Comment: _(FYI:You can upvote or accept answer which really helps you)_

Comment: It works. aslo `$this->db->where('\`time\` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()',null, FALSE);` is right too. ty